# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException; Error en la traducción de un OID en entidad gestora snmp.

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, timer

Lo que pasa es que cuando intengo traducir la información en forma de Response Event a String me sale una excepción, yo pienso que es en este método, quizá estoy ignorando algo, es una clase nueva para mí, así que no la conozco muy bien; este es el código de los métodos que eclipse me muestra:

```
//metodo traducir


public String traducirOid (OID oid) throws IOException 
{
    ResponseEvent event = obtenerOID(new OID[] { oid });
    return event.getResponse().get(0).getVariable().toString();
}
```

y

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            try
            {
                segmentosIN = principal.traducirOid(new OID(principal.OIDin));



                segmentosOUT = principal.traducirOid(new OID(principal.OIDout));

                cuadrotexto.append("segmentos recibidos: " + segmentosIN + "\n" + "segmentos enviados: " + segmentosOUT);
            } catch (IOException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Estos son los otros métodos implementados :

```
public ResponseEvent obtenerOID(OID oids[]) throws IOException
{
    PDU pdu = new PDU();
    for (OID oid : oids) {
        pdu.add(new VariableBinding(oid));
    }

    pdu.setType(PDU.GET);
    ResponseEvent event = snmp.send(pdu, ObtenerTarget(), null);
    if(event != null) {
        return event;
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("GET timed out");
}

private Target ObtenerTarget() {
    Address targetAddress = GenericAddress.parse(address);
    CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();
    target.setCommunity(new OctetString("Redes20182-ganadores"));
    target.setAddress(targetAddress);
    target.setRetries(2);
    target.setTimeout(1500);
    target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);
    return target;
}
```

estoy tratando de traducir un OID que me muestra los segmentos TCP enviados  y recibidos cada cierto tiempo...

espero me puedan ayudar. Saludos y gracias cualquier cosa.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)